# ionic 3 textarea autosize (not ion-textarea)

Tags: ionic3, textarea, autosize

I need autosize (elastic) for <textarea>.
I need to use <textarea>, cannot use <ion-textarea> for other issues.

I was following: [How to autoresize the ion-input field vertically while i am typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47547571/how-to-autoresize-the-ion-input-field-vertically-while-i-am-typing?answertab=active) &  https://stackblitz.com/edit/expandable-input

<ion-textarea> is working:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'ion-textarea[autosize]' })
```

But, Not for <textarea>

```
@Directive({ selector: 'textarea[autosize]' })
```

Here is My Stackblitz (autosize not working): https://stackblitz.com/edit/expandable-input-htjncw

Console error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined ..."

Code:

```
adjust():void {
    const textArea = this.element.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
    textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    textArea.style.height = 'auto';
    textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
  }
```

Comment: Please provide an [mcve] here. Not a link

Comment: Please see the last URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/expandable-input-htjncw

Comment: you will get textarea from `this.element.nativeElement` since you are not using ionic component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding the directive to `textarea` instead of ion-textarea, you can get access to the html element directly from `nativeElement`. You wont be accessing through `getElementsByTagName`

```
adjust():void {
    const textArea = this.element.nativeElement;
    textArea.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    textArea.style.height = 'auto';
    textArea.style.height = textArea.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```